# Member Messaging

Tags: messages

I'm trying to integrate [Comet Chat](http://www.cometchat.com/expressionengine-chat) in my EE site. Whenever a message is sent in Comet Chat between two members of the site, I want that message to be stored in EE's native messaging system. Comet Chat is PHP based and resides on the same server as EE. In one of the hooks of Comet Chat, I have access to the sender's member id, receiver's member id, subject, message, etc.

**Is there a way I can insert this into EE's messaging without having to run a SQL INSERT query** (I'm worried that such an approach might cause potential problems in case I miss something)?

Alternatively:

- Does anyone know of a Comet Chat-like system that I can use with EE?
- Can someone give me some tips on what tables/fields I need to deal with when doing an INSERT into EE's messaging DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately EE doesn't have a nice clean model for simply inserting a private message programatically.

If you were able to send your message data as a `POST`, and it would be happening during the active user's session, then you could possibly use the `Messages` library to do this, but it would also trigger any notifications for new message you have setup in EE, which you may not want.

You can explore further by looking at **/expressionengine//libraries/Messages.php** - particularly the `send_message()` method.

But doing a direct insert is probably best. Do some test messages using EE, then inspect the `exp_message_data` and `exp_message_copies` tables to see how things are inserted. You'll also want to keep the `private_messages` column up-to-date in `exp_members`.

Comment: I have the data that could be sent via `POST` using `curl`. However, although I think I could get `curl` to piggyback off a session, I don't think EE's session works the same as PHP session. That means that my `curl` would be it's own session (effectively meaning that there wouldn't be a logged in member in that session to send the message to).

Will look into `Messages.php`. I'm very reluctant to do the INSERT myself, but if that turns out to be the best option, then so be it.